# Why is my SQL Query only selecting the last entry in a column

Tags: java, sql-server, android-studio

I am trying to connect to SQL Server from an Android app and after days of struggling, I have finally figured it out. Now I have run into a much simpler problem. My select query only selects the last value from the table. The table only contains string values for now as it is a test table. Here is what I wrote in my code.

```java
public void sqlButton(View view) {
    if (connection != null) {
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("Select * from [dbo].[Table_1];");
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                textView.setText(resultSet.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        textView.setText("Connection is null");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is probably that you're overwriting your output text each time.

Write this to a multiline text field, so you see all results:

```
textView.setText(textView.getText() + "\n" + resultSet.getString(1));
```

Comment: Thanks . How do I get It  to iterate through each row instead of displaying all at once >?

Comment: Well.. the `while` loop actually does that. Extend your code to `while (resultSet.next()){ textView.setText(resultSet.getString(1)); System.out.println("Entry: " + resultSet.getString(1)); }` to see that this actually happens

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the select query returns all records in your table. However, the problem is in this part
 `while (resultSet.next()){ textView.setText(resultSet.getString(1));}`
the text in the next loop will replace one in the previous. Therefore, you only see the last one.